# How to properly (securely) dis/connect to a VPN with OpenVPN in Debian?

Tags: debian, security, openvpn, vpn

What's the proper and most secure and convenient way of connecting a VPN over OpenVPN in Debian 9.1 with KDE?

Is that:

- Running `sudo openvpn --config config-path` in the console and leaving the console window opened to connect / stay connected
- Pressing ctrl+c to disconnect

With the most secure and convenient way I mean something that potentially would also allow me to [switch between IPs in OpenVPN without non-VPN traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/1245071/how-to-switch-between-ips-in-openvpn-without-non-vpn-traffic) and [ensures (or allows me to ensure) that I'm connected to my VPN all the time with OpenVPN](https://superuser.com/questions/1245066/how-can-i-make-sure-that-im-connected-to-my-vpn-all-the-time-with-openvpn).

Comment: Your way sounds fine, as far as I know, just inconvenient. You can add the OpenVPN connection information to Network Manager for fast connect/disconnect. You can also run `openvpn --daemon` in your console to do the configuration and go to background and then `pkill openvpn` later to disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

A secure and also easy way is to use `iptables` because it works even before and after the tun device is available.

```
openvpn_if=tun0
vpn_only_addresses=(192.168.123.4 10.1.2.3)
for ip in "${vpn_only_addresses[@]}"; do
    iptables -A OUTPUT -d "$ip" -o "$openvpn_if" -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -d "$ip" -j DROP
done
```

Maybe something similar could be done with advanced routing. Perhaps `ip rule` can work with output interface rules even when the interface does not exist. But that is more complicated that this Netfilter solution.

Answer (score 1):

How to securely connect to openvpn?

From the openvpn docs:

[Running the OpenVPN client with the downloaded client config file:](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides/182-how-to-connect-to-access-server-with-linux-clients.html)

> Usually, the easiest way to install an OpenVPN client is to use the --config argument to specify the location of the downloaded client config file:

```
openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

You can use the `--daemon` option to run openvpn on **background** as a **daemon** according to the [openvpn manpages](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/openvpn/openvpn.8.en.html):

> `--daemon [progname]`
>
> Become a daemon after all initialization functions are completed. This option will cause all message and error output to be sent to the syslog file (such as /var/log/messages), except for the output of scripts and ifconfig commands, which will go to /dev/null unless otherwise redirected. The syslog redirection occurs immediately at the point that --daemon is parsed on the command line even though the daemonization point occurs later. If one of the --log options is present, it will supercede syslog redirection.

```
openvpn --config client.ovpn --daemon
```

How to securely disconnect openvpn?

According to the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/openvpn/openvpn.8.en.html) and the [official docs](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#control) openvpn accept `SIGINIT` and `SIGTERM`signals allowing `openvn` to exit securely.

> `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`
> Causes OpenVPN to exit gracefully.